# Create ng-model dynamically with {{expression}} doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-model

I am working on an angular project where I need to create a form based on an array of questions. I would like to create `ng-model` for each question in the array.

So I have come up with something like the following, but it is not working.

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <label for="{{question.label}}" class="col-md-2 control-label">
        {{question.label}}:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" 
               class="form-control" 
               name="{{question.label}}" 
               data-ng-model={{question.label}}
               required />
        <span class="error"
              data-ng-show="formQuickView.{{question.label}}.$error.required">
            Required!
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could someone help me out for this one ?
Thanks heaps in advance.

Answer (score 7):

```
formQuickView[question.label].$error.required
```

This is regular JavaScript syntax. You want to access the property of `formQuickView` with the name defined by `question.label`.

**Update**

Somehow I missed the main point, the `ng-model`expression. Basically you do the same thing here. You have two choices (technically only one):

- Add an object to your scope, say `questions`, then use `questions[question.label]`.
- When you have a form, then give it a name and an object is added automatically. E.g. `<form name="questions" ....` and the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for that, but my main problem is ng-model. Can I create a model like with {{expression}} at all?

Answer (score 4):

`ng-model` does not work with `{{}}` it considers the string passed to it as an expression referencing a scope property.

I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly. In your code, I think `data-ng-model="question.label"` should work.

If you want to reference a dynamic field specified in your `label` field. Try this with your ng-model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="question[question.label]"/>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3uj0zOiMfNQJev6HX5rg?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks I got it work with something like this ng-model="question.value", then on the save it loop through all my question objects' value property to get values.

Comment: @loveNZ: my statement about `data-ng-model="question.label"` works?